Change query parameter in @QueryParam in JAX-RS
I'm new to JAX-RS, so I apologize if I'm doing something really off base here. I'm consuming an external API (that I have no control over) that requires you to first send a request to get a list of query parameter fields, then you submit another request using the result as a field.
So, for instance, I may get a result that includes a field I want named fieldResult, and then I need to submit a new request that looks something likes /path?fieldResult=value. How can I represent this?
The closest thing I can think of is using @QueryParam, but unlike a @Path and @PathParam combo, there doesn't seem to be a corresponding @Query @QueryParam combo and I can't find any other solution.
public interface SampleInterface {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("{samplePath}")
    Data getData(
          @PathParam("samplePath") String samplePath,
          @QueryParam("{fieldResult}") String value   // something like this, but clearly not exactly
    ); 
}


If we replace @QueryParam("{fieldResult}") with @QueryParam("fieldResult"), it should work as expected.

That would only work if I knew what fieldResult was. I don't know that until getting the result from a previous API call and need to pass it in here as a variable.

Ah. Hm. This might get interesting. Not sure if jax-rs or mp-rest-client have a concept for that...

After reading the comments, it seems like you need to build your URL dynamically. To dynamically build a URI with the query parameters returned from the first request, you could use the UriBuilder class. Then, you could create your request with the previously built URI, and read whatever object you're expecting to be returned.
URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://{host}:{port}/examples")
        .path("my_path")
        .queryParam("param1", "value1")
        .queryParam("param2", "value2")
        ...                               //more query parameters
        .build(host, port);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
MyClass obj = client.target(uri).get(MyClass.class);

Alternatively, you could employ the WebTarget class to dynamically add your query parameters without resorting to aUriBuilder.
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
MyClass obj = client.target("REST_URI")
                  .path("my_path")
                  .queryParam("param1", "value1")
                  .queryParam("param2", "value2")
                  ...                               //more query parameters
                  .get(MyClass.class);

